# Linux - putting timestamps upon process end

Tags: linux

I am executing someone else's program that runs for a VERY long time, so I want to leave it overnight and come back to it in the morning.
But I also want to know exactly when the process ended. How do I do this? (I am very much new an amateur in using Linux)

The program I am running is Hammertime suite by VUSec (on github), calling

`sudo profile/profile 2g myprof.msys >> myres.res`
And this thing runs for at least 2 hours...

Comment: I suppose you can just check the time of modification for the `myres.res` file using `ls`

Comment: Or with `stat -c %y myres.res`

Comment: ah, that's pretty simple. thank you!